# How can I configure an interface with many static IPs

Tags: linux, networking, centos-7

I am setting up a machine that I will use in a test network and which will host many web sites.  I would like this host to have many (on the order of 20k) IP addresses.

I know I could add them all with a script doing, say

```
ip addr add <ip>/<mask> dev eth0
```

and get them all that way.  In fact, that works just fine, but it does not survive a reboot obviously.

If I modify `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` I can assign a static IP that will be persistent, but I don't believe I can assign more than one that way.

Is there a way to assign a lot of static IPs persistently?

I suppose at worst I could create my own IP service and have it run the `ip` commands via a systemd service, but I was wondering if there is a more canonical way to do this.

Comment: There's a good comment at the start of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-aliases` explaining how to setup ranges of ip addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked if it supports 10s of thousands, but it seems that you can specify many addresses within the `ifcfg-` file directly if you tell NetworkManager you're going to do so.

The first step was to tell NetworkManager which I did as

```
nmcli con mod eth0 ipv4.method manual
```

Then I modified `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/eth0` so it had

```
IPADDR0=<ip0>
NETMASK0=<mask0>
IPADDR1=<ip1>
NETMASK1=<mask1>
```

and then `eth0` had both of those addresses (after a reboot at least).

Update: Alas for me, this method only allows up to 256 addresses per interface. (You can see the limit for version 0.9.10 which ships with Fedora 21 in the source on line 1366 of src/settings/pluginos/ifcfg-rh/reader.c if you're interested.)

Answer (score 0):

copy `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0` and edit it

```
DEVICE="eth0:0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR=192.168.230.252
NETWORK=192.168.230.0
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPV6INIT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

you must be on same network.

reboot.

If you can't reboot try `ifconfig eth0:0 up` (didn't test this part)

see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-or-adding-new-network-alias-to-a-network-card-nic/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using the aliases that way has been deprecated and does not seem to work with NetworkManager under Centos 7.  If I create such a file it does not load it, and if I try to do `ifup eth0:0` I lose an address that was on `eth0`--though I haven't tried to diagnose that yet, it could be because they were in the same collision domain

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, when you figured it out.

I know two ways, either individual `ifcfg-eth:x` files for single addresses or `ifcfg-eth0-rangex` files for IP ranges. The file is placed in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` folder.

So first case. Just copy `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0`. Open it in an editor and change *DEVICE* to eth0:0 and *IPADDR* to what you want. The reload your network(`systemctl restart network` on centos 7). Repeat step and increase x with one.

Second case you copy `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0-range0`. Then open the file in an editor and replace *IPADDR* with *IPADDR_START* and add *IPADDR_END* with the corresponding start and stop IPs of the range. Reload the network as mentioned before and the changes are active.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I can't use the `range` one since I don't have contiguous blocks of IPs, and the `:N` aliases are deprecated and don't seem to work with CentOS 7 Network Manager.  If I create `ifcfg-eth0:0` and reboot, I do not get an interface with the address from that file.  If I already had an address on `eth0` and do `ifup eth0:0` I lose at least an address from `eth0` that was in the same collision domain

Comment: Be sure that the DEVICE line in ifcfg-eth0 and ifcfg-eth0:0 are in fact different.

Comment: I was only able to verify on CentOS 6, should have mentioned that in the post.